# What should be the name pattern for k8s service?

Tags: service, kubernetes

I was wondering what is the best name pattern for a service object in k8s environment.
Should it be `%service-name%-service` or just `%service-name%`?

`workflow-service` or just `workflow`?

What are the arguments for both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kubernetes the service dns follow the below pattern

```
<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local
```

i have seen people using svc or service appended to the service name with '-' as the delimiter like below, say, redis

1. redis-service
2. redis-svc
3. redis

all the three are perfectly fine but the first one makes more sense interms of readability and standard way of representing the service object.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, while creating a service it is not needed to append "-service" in the name. The general way of doing it is to name the service same as the name of the pods it is pointing to. Hope this helps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is simply a matter of taste. if you want verbosity, add -service. but since resources are separate anyway, why be verbose.